# JavaScript won't return object, it just returns the section of code

Tags: javascript, object

so im doing a project thats apart of an a udemy course.  I was following along and then i have to return an object to the console to test something, only problem is, it doesnt return the object, it just returns the section of code the object is in, including things like comments.  here's the code:

```
var UIController = (function() {
var DOMstrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    inputDescription: '.add__description',
    inputValue: '.add__value',
    inputBtn: '.add__btn',
    incomeContainer: '.income__list',
    expensesContainer: '.expenses__list',
    budgetLabel: '.budget__value',
    incomeLabel: '.budget__income--value',
    expensesLabel: '.budget__expenses--value',
    percentageLabel: '.budget__expenses--percentage',
    container: '.container',
    expensesPercLabel: '.item__percentage',
    dateLabel: '.budget__title--month'
};

return {
    getinput: function() { 
       var items = {
            type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).nodeValue, 
            description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).nodeValue,
            value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).nodeValue
        }
       return items;
    }
    }
}


)();

   // Global App Controller

    var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {

var ctrlAddItem = function() { 
    // 1. Get the filled input data
    var input = UICtrl.getinput;
    console.log(input);


    // 2. Add the item to the budget controller

    // 3. Add the new item to the user interface

    // 4. Calculate the budget

    // 5. Display the budget on the UI

}


document.querySelector('.add__btn').addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);

// Make the ENTER key do what the CLICK does
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {

        console.log('ENTER was pressed');

        ctrlAddItem();
    }



} );



})(budgetController, UIController);
```

and here is the output:

```
ƒ () { 
       var items = {
            type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).nodeValue, 
            description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).nodeV…
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Please look over your question after you hit "post", to make sure it actually looks right. In this case it definitely doesn't, please edit it and fix that code formatting?

Comment: `UICtrl.getinput()`, adding the `()` to call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var input = UICtrl.getinput;` into `var input = UICtrl.getinput();`

Comment: omg i didnt think it was a function because the function would return an object. It worked, thanks!